# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android

I would like to add a `textview` and a `checkbox` to `linearlayout` view:

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < helperitems.size() ; ++i){
                    final UserHelper u = helperitems.get(i);


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(ContentChatSendMessage.this);
                            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                            linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);


                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams txt_view_params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                            CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(ContentChatSendMessage.this);
                            ch.setId(Integer.parseInt(u.getId()));
                            linearLayout.addView(ch);

                            TextView textView = new TextView(ContentChatSendMessage.this);
                            textView.setLayoutParams(txt_view_params);
                            textView.setText(u.getUsername1());
                            linearLayout.addView(ch);

                            arr_chs.add(ch);
                            lay_lin_parent.addView(linearLayout);

                        }
                    });

                }
```

my layout :

```
<LinearLayout
...

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_lin_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp">

    </LinearLayout>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

but I get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to add the `CheckBox ch` to `linearLayout` twice. The second `linearLayout.addView()` call in the loop should be: `linearLayout.addView(textView);`.